# Is older MTG Online client not supported any more?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-online

I have both older MTG Online III (version 3.4.82.414) and the very latest MTG Online client installed.

The older one fails when running both Kicker.exe or  Renamer.exe since it tries to reach which seems unreachable

http://mtgodownload1.onlinegaming.wizards.com/mtgov3

Is older MTG Online client not supported any more?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with the paper card game. Therefore, I think this question belongs on Arqade, where they have a tag specifically for MTGO called [mtg-online](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/mtg-online/info). I've flagged it so that hopefully a moderator will move it.

Comment: @Rainbolt Our help center does say that questions about computer versions of board/card games are fine - if you think we should subdivide that into about both (okay) and about only the computer version (migrate), maybe we should discuss on meta and try to revise the help center? Not sure it's super-friendly to close/migrate questions that the help seems to say are on topic...

Comment: Meta question: http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1193/are-questions-specifically-about-the-computer-version-of-a-game-on-topic

Comment: @Jefromi I think the current policy should be applied with some common sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's no longer supported. They [announced on June 26](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/magic-online-v3-date-and-new-client-update-2014-06-26):

> ... we'll be turning off access to the current Magic Online client (aka V3) on **July 16**.

And on the day of [posted this update](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/magic-online-new-beginnings-2014-07-16).

(And of course, if you try to download it, you can only get the new version - that ought to be a pretty good sign too.)

Comment: No longer working/supported and that's a real shame considering the already multiple reported bugs that are still going (like replays not working everytime you get to pick some kind of X).

Comment: @dnLL You seem surprised that complex software has bugs. For a company that isn't a software company, I'm surprised there aren't more bugs, honestly.

Comment: @dnLL More to the point, this is not Wizards' issue tracker or customer support - I'm sure you're genuinely frustrated and there are real bugs to report, but this isn't the place.

Comment: I'm surprised, yes, because most of the bugs are a few years old now. I am myself a programmer and complex or not, a bug about an interaction about 2 cards or something making the replay function completely unusable (why keep offering it?) should not be that complicated to fix. You are right to say that this isn't the place but WotC doesn't do anything about it anyway.

Comment: @dnLL Then since we all agree this isn't the place, how about we all delete our comments and let this just be an answer to the actual question.